# Date is automatically resetting to beginning once it reaches the month end in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a matrix table which contains a day(currentdate value) as row group and month as a column group. The column group has two child columns one contains the data represents a value which falls on that particular day of that month and another is a running value. like wise the column values represents for current and previous month. Now the problem is for the month which doesn't have the date 31 contains the data which actually belongs to the particular months start date data. to understand how the data is populating for that particular row I added a column of date field. it shows the start date of the month.

I would like to know how to avoid this automatic data resetting.

[Sample image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vpbg.png)

Comment: As  a simple solution why not include the maximum number of days in each month in the SQL query. A simple IIF in SSRS would then get around this problem e.g. `IIF(mydata.date > mydata.myMaxMonthDays,0,mydata.date)`

Comment: myMaxMonthDays could be found by using the following (substitute your date for `GETDATE() ---SELECT datepart(d,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))) as myMaxMonthDays`